# Why does 'mkt_carrier_fl_num AS flight' return a syntax error 42601?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgres and everything databases. I'm learning through a Pluralsight course and have finally managed to import a database. Following along with what the teacher is typing out, I query:

```
SELECT  fl_date, 
        mkt_carrier AS airline
        mkt_carrier_fl_num AS flight
        origin,
        dest
  FROM  performance
 WHERE  origin = 'ORD'
```

.. from a database that came with the course files, and get back this:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "mkt_carrier_fl_num"
LINE 3:   mkt_carrier_fl_num AS flight
          ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 45
```

I've googled the error code but apparently this can entail many different things. I have no idea where to go from here. Literally every function in this program is a mystery to me.

Please help.

Comment: comma , is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  fl_date
        ,mkt_carrier AS airline -- comma before the start of the column name
        ,mkt_carrier_fl_num AS flight
        ,origin
        ,dest
  FROM  performance
 WHERE  origin = 'ORD';
```